# How can make the width of string the same in Android?

Tags: android, android-studio

There are 3 strings, each the length of string is the same, there are spaces in the those strings. After I fill the 3 strings in a ListView control, I find the width of the 3 row isn't the same.

How can I make the width of string the same in Android? Thanks!

BTW, I use Android Studio. The min API is 9.

[image]

```
string1= "a      b"
string2= "aa     b"
string3= "aaa    b"

ListView lv=(ListView)findViewById(R.id.listView);
String[] COUNTRIES=new String[]{"a     b","aa    b","aaa   b"};
lv.setAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, COUNTRIES));
```

Comment: If it wont be a big issue for you, can you use an extra view in your row layout to achieve what you are doing.. things will be much easier as compared to dynamically creating extra logic. Maybe adding a linear layout as parent and then setting the orientation as horizontal and then adding the two views to it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unless you're using a monospaced font, achieving what you wanted is going to be quite difficult. Non-monospaced fonts has different width for each of the characters they posses.

However, there's a workaround to this using layout arrangement. Here's an example:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:layout_width="300dp"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <LinearLayout
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="0.7">

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
            android:text="A"
            android:id="@+id/textView2"/>

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
            android:text="AAA"
            android:id="@+id/textView4"/>

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
            android:text="AAAAA"
            android:id="@+id/textView5"/>
    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="0.3">

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
            android:text="B"
            android:id="@+id/textView3"/>

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
            android:text="BBB"
            android:id="@+id/textView6"/>

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
            android:text="BBBB"
            android:id="@+id/textView7"/>
    </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

The above code will produce a layout like this:

[image]

Comment: Thanks! What kind of  monospaced font can I select to fit all phone, and fit API 9 and above?

Comment: AFAIK, you can use any fonts as long as you ship them alongside your app (inside the APK). Android itself also has a monospaced font built-in. You can use it and not worry about availability. As a side-note, monospaced font isn't going to be suitable for "normal" use-cases. As its fixed width may seem unnatural for the eye of your user.

Comment: Thanks!  To ridsatrio: Would you please have a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31017025/how-can-i-make-the-textview-controls-which-contain-characters-a-have-the-same

Comment: I will. But please can you accept my answer? It seemed to have helped you. Of course you're free to ignore this should you felt the otherwise. :)

Answer (score 0):

add the views programmatically to the linear layout i have done in one of my program

xml (no of linearlayout as rows)

```
  <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/ansrow2"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:horizontalSpacing="4dp"
            android:numColumns="10"
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:paddingEnd="10dp"
            android:paddingStart="10dp"
            android:verticalSpacing="10dp" >
        </LinearLayout>


for (int i = 0; i < list2.size(); i++) {
                text = new TextView(MainActivity.this);
                text.setBackgroundColor(Color.WHITE);
                text.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER);
                text.setText("" + list2.get(i).toString().toLowerCase());
                text.setPadding(10, 10, 10, 10);
                text.setTextSize(35f);
                text.setTypeface(rail);

                text.setLayoutParams(new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(
                        LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
                        5f));

                text.setId(101 + i);
                if (i < 10) {
                    ansrow2.addView(text);
                } else {
                    ansrow1.addView(text);
                }
                text.setOnClickListener(this);
            }
```

try to understand the code and implement it according to your needs