# How can I make the TextView controls which contain characters "A" have the same width with text align left and control align right?

Tags: android

I hope the TextView controls which contain characters "A" have the same width with text align left and control align right , so I have set TextView controls which contain characters "A" with max width="150dp",
and I have set  `android:gravity="left"` and  `android:layout_gravity="right"`

I think I can get the result AA.png, but in fact the result is BB.png

**I hope (AA.png)**

[image]

**Current (BB.png)**

[image]

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<RelativeLayout  xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:background="@drawable/border_ui"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView
        xmlns:ads="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        android:id="@+id/adView"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        ads:adSize="SMART_BANNER"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        ads:adUnitId="@string/ad_unit_id" />


    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_above="@+id/linearLayout1"
        android:layout_below="@+id/adView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        >

        <LinearLayout
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:gravity="left"
            android:layout_gravity="right"
            android:layout_weight="0.5">

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="150dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
                android:text="A"
                android:id="@+id/textView2"/>

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="150dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
                android:text="AAA"
                android:id="@+id/textView4"/>

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="150dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
                android:text="AAAAA"
                android:id="@+id/textView5"/>
        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="0.5">

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
                android:text="B"
                android:id="@+id/textView3"/>

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
                android:text="BBB"
                android:id="@+id/textView6"/>

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
                android:text="BBBB"
                android:id="@+id/textView7"/>
        </LinearLayout>
    </LinearLayout>





    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/linearLayout1"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:weightSum="4" >

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/btnReturn"
            style="@style/myTextMedium"
            android:layout_width="0dip"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:text="@string/BtnReturn" />
    </LinearLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can accomplish that by adding an extra LinearLayout and removing the 150dp limitation:

> ```
> <com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView
>     xmlns:ads="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
>     android:id="@+id/adView"
>     android:layout_width="wrap_content"
>     android:layout_height="wrap_content"
>     ads:adSize="SMART_BANNER"
>     android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
>     ads:adUnitId="@string/ad_unit_id" />
>
>
> <LinearLayout
>     android:layout_above="@+id/linearLayout1"
>     android:layout_below="@+id/adView"
>     android:layout_width="match_parent"
>     android:layout_height="match_parent"
>     android:orientation="horizontal"
>     >
>
>     <LinearLayout
>         android:orientation="vertical"
>         android:layout_width="wrap_content"
>         android:layout_height="wrap_content"
>         android:gravity="left"
>         android:layout_weight="0.5">
>         <LinearLayout
>             android:layout_width="wrap_content"
>             android:layout_height="wrap_content"
>             android:orientation="vertical"
>             android:layout_gravity="right">
>         <TextView
>             android:layout_width="wrap_content"
>             android:layout_height="wrap_content"
>             android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
>             android:text="A"
>             android:id="@+id/textView2"/>
>
>         <TextView
>             android:layout_width="wrap_content"
>             android:layout_height="wrap_content"
>             android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
>             android:text="AAA"
>             android:id="@+id/textView4"/>
>
>         <TextView
>             android:layout_width="150dp"
>             android:layout_height="wrap_content"
>             android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
>             android:text="AAAAA"
>             android:id="@+id/textView5"/>
>         </LinearLayout>
>     </LinearLayout>
>
>     <LinearLayout
>         android:orientation="vertical"
>         android:layout_width="wrap_content"
>         android:layout_height="wrap_content"
>         android:layout_weight="0.5">
>
>         <TextView
>             android:layout_width="wrap_content"
>             android:layout_height="wrap_content"
>             android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
>             android:text="B"
>             android:id="@+id/textView3"/>
>
>         <TextView
>             android:layout_width="wrap_content"
>             android:layout_height="wrap_content"
>             android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
>             android:text="BBB"
>             android:id="@+id/textView6"/>
>
>         <TextView
>             android:layout_width="wrap_content"
>             android:layout_height="wrap_content"
>             android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
>             android:text="BBBB"
>             android:id="@+id/textView7"/>
>     </LinearLayout>
> </LinearLayout>
>
>
>
>
>
> <LinearLayout
>     android:id="@+id/linearLayout1"
>     android:layout_width="fill_parent"
>     android:layout_height="wrap_content"
>     android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
>     android:gravity="center"
>     android:orientation="horizontal"
>     android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
>     android:weightSum="4" >
>
>     <Button
>         android:id="@+id/btnReturn"
>         style="@style/myTextMedium"
>         android:layout_width="0dip"
>         android:layout_height="fill_parent"
>         android:layout_gravity="center"
>         android:layout_weight="1"
>         android:text="@string/BtnReturn" />
> </LinearLayout>
> ```

Comment: Thanks! Your code works. You separate android:gravity="left" and android:layout_gravity="right" into two LinearLayout,  but I don't understand why your code can work and my code can't

Comment: The reason for that is that in your code, the LinearLayout that you're trying to gravitate right, doesn't have room to move, since it's weight is 0.5 or half of its parent. In my code, the inner LinearLayout has room to move because its width is wrap_content. Please accept my answer if it worked for you. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

i guess you will use

```
 <LinearLayout
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:gravity="left"
            android:layout_gravity="right"
            android:layout_weight="0.5"
            android:layoutMarginLeft="20dp">
```

**android:layoutMarginLeft="20dp"**

Comment: Thanks! but maybe android:layoutMarginLeft="20dp" is not a good way, when the app run under a huge screen,20dp maybe less